# Как в wordpress правильно редактировать файлы из wp-includes

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Суть проблемы, на страницах сайта, где есть комментарии на мобильной версии сайта при клике по кнопкам `Ответить` или `Отменить ответ` возникает ошибка `Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.`, возникает она в файле `../wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=5.8.1`. Поискав решение подобной проблемы, нашел решение. В вышеупомянутом файле для `e.preventDefault()` нужно дополнительно прописать условие `if (e.cancelable)`, и это помогло, если изменить файл напрямую. Но это не правильно при любом обновлении WP все правки слетят. Вопрос, как можно c помощью functions.php изменить данный файл правильно, чтобы изменения сохранились навсегда? Конкретный участок кода в файле:

```
function a(e) {
        var t = g(b.commentReplyTitleId),
            n = t && t.firstChild.textContent,
            d = this,
            o = m(d, "belowelement"),
            i = m(d, "commentid"),
            r = m(d, "respondelement"),
            t = m(d, "postid"),
            n = m(d, "replyto") || n;
        o && i && r && t && !1 === v.addComment.moveForm(o, i, r, t, n) && e.preventDefault()
}
```

Нужно изменить на:

```
function a(e) {
    if (e.cancelable) {
        var t = g(b.commentReplyTitleId),
            n = t && t.firstChild.textContent,
            d = this,
            o = m(d, "belowelement"),
            i = m(d, "commentid"),
            r = m(d, "respondelement"),
            t = m(d, "postid"),
            n = m(d, "replyto") || n;
        o && i && r && t && !1 === v.addComment.moveForm(o, i, r, t, n) && e.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ядро трогать нельзя. Нужно правильно писать свои плагины-темы.

Comment: Зачем Вы удаляете метку javascript, если у вас вопрос и сниппет в целом по JS?

Comment: Можете обратиться также сюда https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/